# C#: Can't download videos in bulk?

Tags: c#, .net

So I'm trying to download a list of strings, which are MP4 videos. This code works when theres only one video to download, yet doesn't if there are multiple on the list?

If there are multiple it downloads it, its always 154kb in size, and no length. Its esentially corrupted and can't be watched, that's exactly what windows also tells me when I open it.

Can anyone help? Am I not doing something I should be?

```
public static void DownloadFiles(IList<string> files)
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        DownloadFile(file, file.Location);
    }
}

private static void DownloadFile(string url, string fileName)
{
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36");
        webClient.DownloadFile(url, fileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: just a guess, but i suspect it has something to do with what's being passed to the method, rather than the method itself

Comment: Show us the `Location` interface you injected into `string`. Always post an [MCVE].

Comment: what does fiddler or wireshark show is going over the wire. I suspect your big, same size download is a huge javascript UI telling you 'no idea what you are asking for'